# Android: Периодический опрос сервера

Tags: java, android

Уже кучу информации изучил и везде мнения расходятся. Вопросов несколько:

На данный момент организовал Service, который запускается через `alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 300000, pendingIntent);`
alarmManager объявлен в главной Activity (менюшка с фрагментами)

1. Как работают месенжеры по типу Skype, Viber? У них свои пуш серверы, или там другие технологии используются? Слышал что-то о websocket.
2. Как лучше реализовать постоянный опрос сервера с наименьшей тратой батареи телефона?

Comment: Во первых, вы хотите получить ответ на 2 вопроса. Это вредно для форума. Конечно может быть полезно лично вам, но этот форум создан не лично для вас. Поэтому - соблюдайте пожалуйств правила. Во вторых, вы задаете вопрос, который зависит от личного мнения каждого. Нету, как вы догадываетесь, единственного самого лучшего способа.

Comment: Кроме того, как работает Skype и Viber достоверно известно только их создателям,  и я сомневаюсь, что они захотят вам рассказать

Comment: Если кому не понятно, вопрос тут один на самом деле: как оптимально сделать обмен сообщениями?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Больше года назад пришлось потратить некоторое время на изучение второго вопроса. Поиск через Google вывел меня только на один результат исследования по этой теме, где было сказано что smart polling может быть экономичнее использования websockets.

Что под этим подразумевалось?

Если просто тупо опрашивать сервер с постоянным интервалом, то чудес ждать не стоит. Батарея будет расходоваться неоптимально. Websockets экономичнее.

Нужно быть smart :) Анализировать поведение пользователя, знать логику бэкенда и подстраивать интервал опроса соответственно этому.

Пример, пользователь отправил что-то на сервер, вы знаете что это попадет в какую-то очередь и раньше 30 секунд результата ждать не стоит. Нечего зря бомбить сервер раньше времени. Либо пользователь читает длинный пост, можно ждать пока дочитает, потом запросить сервер есть ли что нового.
Так же слушать системные события, собирать запросы и посылать пачками, кэшировать результаты и всякое такое.

Сложно? Да. Стоит того? Да. Не хочется делать? Тогда websockets, а лучше push.